# Is there a way to use a .doc file as a page in doxygen?

Tags: ms-word, doxygen

Specifically I want to be able to use it as the main page, which I know to to do using the `\mainpage` command for `.html` and `.md` files, but I'm wondering if there's a way that I can make a page be a `.doc` without having to manually export it (or start a new file).

Comment: What is that `.doc` file for a format? A MS Word document? Then you should try to convert it to `.md`. Try out [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/).

Comment: Yeah, but I was hoping there was a way to keep using MS word to edit this document.

Comment: You would need to re-convert it every time the word document has changed when running Doxygen. I'd recommend creating a script for that which converts the document and subsequently runs doxygen.